# add/update array in collection with firestore and react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to add an object in the array "steps" from collection task, without delete the objects that already inside the array

```
                
queryDocumentSnapshot.ref.set({steps:[{title:newStep,completed:false}]});
alert('This task has been updated');
```

But when I use set, its deleted all the old fields.. Hoe can I update (add new element in the array) without delete..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#update_elements_in_an_array), you need to use `arrayUnion`:

```
queryDocumentSnapshot.ref.update({
    steps: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({title:newStep,completed:false})
})
.then(() => {
   alert('This task has been updated');
});
```